# Run bash on android

Tags: java, android

I try run bash on android using next code:

```
    Process proc = null;

    try 
   {
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash");                      

    } catch (IOException e) 
   {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
   if (proc != null)
   {
    //some code
   }else
    System.out.println("NULL");
```

But proc always is null. What I do wrong?

Comment: Just checking: Is the device rooted? And perhaps you should use /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash?

Comment: This related question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094562/how-to-run-bash-script-in-my-android

Answer (score 3):

Bash is usually not available on Android devices, and the location of the bin directory is different too. Try this one:

```
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/sh");
```